# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-error

```
little = 0
biggest = 0
a = int(input())
b = 0
while a != 0:
  if a >= 150 and a <= 190:
    b += 1
    if a > biggest:
        biggest = a
    elif a < little:
        little = a
  a = input(int())
  
print(b)
print(little, biggest)
```

Comment: Сравните третью строку с двенадцатой

Answer (score 2):

У вас в строке:

```
a = input(int())
```

допущена ошибка, надо `input` и `int` поменять местами:

```
a = int(input())
```